# Datatables: How to search for rendered(changed) data when serverSide option is true

Tags: datatables

I'm using datatables 1.10.

I want to search for rendered(changed) data when serverSide option is true.

Example

1. server returns `m` or `f` for `gender` field.
2. use render function: `Male` for `m`, `Female` for `f`
3. search `Male` failed, because server doesn't have any `Male` gender

Here is some datatables initial code.

```
$('#UserList').dataTable({
  serverSide: true,
  columns: [
    {data: 'gender', render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
      if (type === 'display' || type === 'filter') {
        switch (data) {
          case 'm': return 'Male';
          case 'f': return 'Female';
          default: return 'Unknown';
        }
      }
      return data;
...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an excerpt from [official documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide). By definition, with server-side processing enabled, client-side filtering will not be performed.

> Client-side processing - where filtering, paging and sorting calculations are all performed in the web-browser.
>
> Server-side processing - where filtering, paging and sorting calculations are all performed by a server.

With `serverSide: true`, render will not be called with `type` equal to `filter`.

The solution would be to adjust your server-side code to handle this special case, i.e. when parameter `search[value]` in request contains word `Male`, include records where your `gender` field equals `m`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I will try custom search checkbox if user check `Male`, then request gender = m to server.

Comment: If you want to share your work I think you can help to of people :)